# Why React app deployment to GitHub Pages works differently using gh-pages?

Tags: reactjs, web-deployment, github-pages

I want to know why deploying a React app to GitHub Pages is different than the usual way of creating a repository by naming it as {username}.github.io then pushing the build files there.

According to GitHub documentation not following the naming convention won't work but gh-pages creates a repository that doesn't follow the convention and still works but at http://{username}.github.io/{repo_name}.

And why is that we cannot deploy the app at http://{username}.github.io?

Thank you.

Comment: This might help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54575701/how-to-deploy-my-react-app-to-github-user-pages

Comment: Welcome to SO! You should be able to deploy to this username, or activate a `/path` subdomain from `{username}.github.io`. What's the problem you're having in doing these things? Assuming your React app is all client-side, then it shouldn't be any different than any other site.